# Servlet and TLS

Tags: java, http, servlets, glassfish-3, ssl

I'm developing a simple web services using Java EE Servlets.

My clients are a simple java apps (no browsers), so I need to secure my communication using TLS (or SSL v3). About Application server, I'm using Glassfish v3.
For example, I need to transfer some data from client to server within a HTTP Post Request into a secure connection.
There are some external libraries, server configurations or tutorial that can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side you must somehow expose your servlets via HTTPS. If you are using [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat), check out [SSL Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). If you have an Apache web server in front, see: [Apache SSL/TLS Encryption](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/).

On the client side [ssl](/questions/tagged/ssl) and [https](/questions/tagged/https) support is built into JDK, just call any `https://...` address using [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html). However remember that the certificate your server uses must be trusted - either confirmed by some authority or added manually on the client. Self-signed certificates by default won't be accepted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I didn't understand what you mean with "expose servlets via HTTPS". There are some annotations to use? I'm using Glassfish 3.1.

Comment: @Cecco: for Glassfish (sorry, I missed that) check out: https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/using_ssl_in_glassfish and http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/. And no, SSL is only a configuration matter, servlets have no support for it. Your servlet/web container needs to support it.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've understand SSL configuration with asadmin command to allow browsers to secure connections. So if I would to "protect" my POST data I should implement a cypher mechanism manually on server (servlet) and client (java app) side?

Comment: @Cecco: I don't know Glassfish, but it should be enough to put your trusted certificate on the server side somewhere and then just connect using `https` on the client side.

Comment: Now I'm following http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/ tutorial and I try to call a servlet using #https on the client side. I accept your answer ;) Thanks a lot.